# Redux-react jwt-decode error InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, decode, jwt

I am doing react-redux authorization, and I have an error when I use action "LOGOUT."
it is my reducer : 
`

```
const loginRegLogoutReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (!state){
        return {}
    }
    if(localStorage.authToken && action.type === "CHECK_LOGIN" && localStorage.authToken !== null){
        let  user = jwt(localStorage.authToken)
        return  {username: user.username, id: user.sub, birthday: user.birthday}
    }
    if(action.type = 'LOGIN'){
        let user = jwt(action.token)
        localStorage.setItem('authToken', action.token)
        return  {username: user.username, id: user.sub, birthday: user.birthday}
    }
    if(action.type = 'LOGOUT'){
        localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
    }
    return state
}
```

`
and this what i am doing :

`<i class="fa fa-sign-out logout" onClick={() => store.dispatch({type: "LOGOUT"})}/>`
                                          so this give me error
    **InvalidTokenError: Invalid token specified**

Comment: Hey @dude.. can you tell us what gives the error. Probably a network call. ? Probably you are making a request call after removing the token ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to clear the state too in case if there some code that looks at state and executes some code it shouldn't